# Set a checkbox based on its value

Tags: php, javascript, json, checkbox

I am currently working on a javascript and php project. I have a checkbox array that have the same id `chkCategory` and the name `chkCategory[]`. I then have PHP return some json that contains the various categories and I want to set each checkbox checked attribute for each category that was in the json. The only thing that identifies each checkbox is the value. I.e. the json may have a value `MyCategory` so the checkbox that has the value `MyCategory` should be set.

I know you can use `$("#myCheckBoxId").attr("checked", true)` for an individual checkbox but not sure how to do this for a specific checkbox with a certain value.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: You can't work with the same ID in JavaScript.

Comment: This is true - using the same ID in more than one place causes unexpected and unpredictable outcomes. Look what it did to @null's username :P (Have we met before? Have I made that joke already?)

Comment: @NULL, you _can,_ e.g., `$('input[id="someID"]')`, but of course you _shouldn't need to_ because you shouldn't have duplicated IDs in your HTML in the first place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard CSS attribute selectors in JQuery.  For example:

```
$("input[value=MyCategory]")
```

will select the input tag with attribute `value=MyCategory`.  If there are different types of `input`s with that value, you could also select on `type=checkbox`:

```
$("input[type=checkbox][value=MyCategory]")
```

Comment: @Lix sure, but the selector above would work if there aren't other input types with that value -- depends how selective you need to be.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the index, you could do...

```
$("input[name='MyCategory']").eq(n).prop("checked", true);
```

If you don't have jQuery...

```
document.getElementsByName("MyCategory")[n].checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain javascript it would look like this:

```
​document.querySelector('input[value=checkboxValue]').checked = true;​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

where `checkboxValue` is the value of your checkbox